# Is this possible to get div element position in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is this possible to get div element position in JQuery?

homebox is hidden and having right as 0px , I want to animate homebox to container.

so i tried this code

```
   $("#homebox").animate({ left:$("container").position().left}, 500);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) your looking for.

```
$("#homebox").animate({ left: $("#container").offset().left }, 500);
```

The above should *hopefully* work.

Also, should not the `container` have an ID? `#` is missing from your selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) or [Position](http://api.jquery.com/position/)

> Offset - Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements, relative to the document.
>
> Position - Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set
>   of matched elements, relative to the offset parent.